# Java api does not work on new java version

Tags: java, eclipse, jnlp

Api does not seem to work after I updated Java . I have found a way by disabling byte code verification .

I have also found a documentation  [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources) but not sure ho to use it . Where do I put JNLP Syntax ? Can I use it with eclipse ?
Or should I get keep both java versions ?
Any brief description will be appreciated .

Similar  question was asked but There ambiguity in the answer. I would like a definite answer though .

Comment: I don't think there is such a feature. Why would anyone enable that? The point of JNLP is to have a reasonably secure way to run code that is downloaded off the net. Part of that is byte code verification.

Comment: Is there any way to stop byte code verification in for java 7 @Thilo

Comment: See the linked duplicate. You can set some parameters for your own machine, but you cannot set it inside of JNLP for others. Why do you even need that?

Comment: I do not need to use jnlp .. I have used some api which do not work in new java versions . Thats why i need to disable it . Or should I just install another java ?@Thilo

Comment: I would find out why that code does not work, and try to fix it. Stackoverflow can help with that. If it is a commercially available or open source library, there is probably already a fixed version to be had. If that is not possible, move to another library. Last resort, yes, keep an older Java around (but only use it for that one application).

Comment: As I said there is no option to update to a new library .  And there is not any option to fix the old one either . So I have to disable verification or keep a older version of java .  But I would also like to learn how to disable it also . @Thilo

Comment: `-noverify` (as described in the link) does not work?

Comment: I am not sure how to use jnlp thats the problem ..  or there is any other way then that of jnlp